# MongoDB collections with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing my own personal project to learn new technologies `(angular, nodejs, express, mongodb)`. I have `login/register` users `(collection: users)`, real sport players (`collection: players)`. Now, i am doing `user_teams (collection: user_team)` and there i have all positions like `goalkeeper, midfielder, attacker`. So User create User_team and in user_team he will choose players from collection players.

What is the best way to do? I should have it split, so players, user_teams, user, or in one collection user I should have user_team?

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to checkout mongodb / mongoose and read more about subdocuments and related options.  as you most pobably know 'relations' are not built and maintained as in standard sql.  Maybe you can find some ideas there on how to do things.

Comment: Thank you for idea, I check it, you said true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document schema may fit your requirements. Create only one collection userTeam with the following schema

```
{
    "user" : "user1",
    "team" : [ 
        {
            "playerName" : "Player1",
            "role" : "goalkeeper"
        }, 
        {
            "playerName" : "Player2",
            "role" : "midfielder"
        }, 
        {
            "playerName" : "Player3",
            "role" : "attacker"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, I use it. And I have last question to this, that playerName in your "json" schema, should I use playerId from players?

Comment: My suggestion is to don't create the users and players collection. Store all details in userTeam collection itself. Only one collection is enough to achieve your functionality.

Comment: So in angular I want to load all players (real players), and this players will choose users. And about this real players I want to have same details like statistic about their goals etc ... So it is useful to use only one collection ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the help of the MongoDB aggregation framework.